# How can I convert all columns from my Excel file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, converters

I want to convert all columns (59 columns) from my excel file to a dataframe, specifying the types.
Some columns are a string, others dates, other int and more.
I know I can use a converter in a read_excel method.
but I have a lot of columns and I don't want write converter={'column1': type1, 'column2': type2, ..., 'column59': type59}

my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import recordlinkage
import xrld

fileName = 'C:/Users/Tito/Desktop/banco ZIKA4.xlsx'
strcols = [0, 5, 31, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 45]
datecols = [3, 4, 29, 30, 32, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
intcols = [33, 43, 59]
booleancols = [6, ..., 28]
df = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=0, true_values=['s'], false_values=['n'], converters={strcols: str, intcols: np.int, booleancols: np.bool, datecols: pd.to_datetime})
print(df.iat[1, 31], df.iat[1, 32], df.iat[1, 33])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iiuc your code doesn't work because the `converters` kwarg doesn't allow lists of several columns as keys to functions.

What you can do is to create dicts instead of lists and provide the concatenated dicts to `converters`:

```
strcols = {c: str for c in [0, 5, 31, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 45]}
datecols = {c: pd.to_datetime for c in [3, 4, 29, 30, 32, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]}
intcols = {c: np.int for c in [33, 43, 59]}
booleancols = {c: np.bool for c in range(6, 29)}
conv_fcts = {**strcols, **datecols, **intcols, **booleancols}

df = pd.read_excel(fileName, converters=conv_fcts, sheet_name=0, true_values=['s'], false_values=['n'])
```